# Android - Back Stack Profiler - is there a tool or printable property?

Tags: android, back-stack

I would like to better understand back stack in my application. Is there any tool in Android Studio, library or just I can access and print some property to get current stack of activities that are in Back Stack? I would like to see how this back stack changes while I am navigating through the app.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549366/print-the-current-back-stack-in-the-log